Unable to throw custom error messages while using Joi package in frontend
This is my first attempt in trying to use joi in frontend and the issue i am facing is that i am not getting custom errors when i try with bad data.
Here is my code in the validation.js
import Joi from "joi";

export const loginSchema = Joi.object({
  email: Joi.string()
    .pattern(new RegExp("^[^@\\s]+@[domainName]\\.(com|in)$"))
    .email({
      minDomainSegments: 2,
      tlds: { allow: ["com", "in"] },
    })
    .required()
    .messages({
      "string.email": "Email must be a valid email",
      "string.pattern.base":
        "Email domain must be [domainName] and end with .com or .in",
      "any.required": "Email is a required field",
    }),
  password: Joi.string()
    .pattern(new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$"))
    .required()
    .messages({
      "string.base": "Password should be a type of text",
      "string.empty": "Password cannot be an empty field",
      "string.pattern.base":
        "Password should have a minimum length of 3 and a maximum length of 30, and contain only letters and numbers",
      "any.required": "Password is a required field",
    }),
});



For the frontend I am using Ionic Vue version 8 and here is the crucial code from that file as it is Too long;
                  <!-- Email -->
                  <ion-item>
                    <ion-input
                      placeholder="Email Address"
                      label-placement="stacked"
                      color="light"
                      type="email"
                      v-model.trim="form.email"
                      @ionBlur="validateField('email')"
                      :error-text="errors.email"
                    >
                      <ion-icon
                        slot="start"
                        :icon="mailOutline"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      ></ion-icon>
                    </ion-input>
                  </ion-item>

                  <!-- Password -->
                  <ion-item>
                    <ion-input
                      placeholder="Password"
                      label-placement="stacked"
                      color="light"
                      type="password"
                      v-model.trim="form.password"
                      @ionBlur="validateField('password')"
                      :error-text="errors.password"
                    >
                      <ion-icon
                        slot="start"
                        :icon="keyOutline"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      ></ion-icon>
                      <ion-input-password-toggle
                        slot="end"
                        color="dark"
                      ></ion-input-password-toggle>
                    </ion-input>
                  </ion-item>
    <script setup>
    import { loginSchema } from "../../services/Validators";
    import { reactive } from "vue";
const form = reactive({
  email: "",
  password: "",
});
const errors = reactive({
  email: null,
  password: null,
});

const validateField = (field) => {
  const data = { [field]: form[field] };

  console.log("Data: ", { ...data });
  console.log("datatype: ", typeof data[field]);

  const schema = loginSchema.extract(field);
  const { error } = schema.validate(
    { email: data[field] },
    { abortEarly: false }
  );

  console.log(`Validation error for ${field}:`, { ...error });

  errors[field] = error ? error.details[0].message : null;
};

</script>

Can someone Guide me as to what is wrong here cause when i log the error with some bad email here is the log that I get
{
    "_original": {
        "email": "dsfasdf@sdf.asd"
    },
    "details": [
        {
            "message": "\"value\" must be a string",
            "path": [],
            "type": "string.base",
            "context": {
                "label": "value",
                "value": {
                    "email": "dsfasdf@sdf.asd"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

ideally what should be logged is:
"string.pattern.base": "Email domain must be [domainName] and end with .com or .in",

Initially, i though I might not be sending the right data format  or datatype format however when i printed data  and dataType of the field this is what i see
data
{
    "email": "sdfsd@asdf.ds"
}

dataType
datatype:  string

Validation error for email:
{
    "_original": {
        "email": "sdfsd@asdf.ds"
    },
    "details": [
        {
            "message": "\"value\" must be a string",
            "path": [],
            "type": "string.base",
            "context": {
                "label": "value",
                "value": {
                    "email": "sdfsd@asdf.ds"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

since i am using Joi.object() where the keys match the schema keys and the values are the data to be validated i ruled out that it was due to incorrect data type or value.
When i test this schema with online tools/ sandboxes it works perfectly fine, however it not when i run it in the project. i am sure i am overlooking something, Please help me find that out

You can pass string instead of object

You cannot pass object when schema is extracted, so just pass the email string it will work
 let email = data[field];
 const { error } = schema.validate(
    email,
    { abortEarly: false }
 );

And some recommendation, you won't need required method in each property if all the properties in a object are required.
Instead use prefs method like below
const loginSchema = Joi.object({
    email: Joi.string()
        .pattern(new RegExp('^[^@\\s]+@[domainName]\\.(com|in)$'))
        .email({
            minDomainSegments: 2,
            tlds: { allow: ['com', 'in'] }
        })
        .messages({
            'string.email': 'Email must be a valid email',
            'string.pattern.base': 'Email domain must be [domainName] and end with .com or .in',
            'any.required': 'Email is a required field'
        }),
    password: Joi.string().pattern(new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$')).messages({
        'string.base': 'Password should be a type of text',
        'string.empty': 'Password cannot be an empty field',
        'string.pattern.base':
            'Password should have a minimum length of 3 and a maximum length of 30, and contain only letters and numbers',
        'any.required': 'Password is a required field'
    })
}).prefs({ presence: 'required' }); // Here 

presence: 'required' tells that all the properties are required
Joi Doc

Thank you for the fix and the recommendation, Just a note  since i am calling this function on email and password doing this
let email = data[field];
const { error } = schema.validate(
    email,
    { abortEarly: false }
 ); 

will limit it to email only, i instead kept it
const data = { [field]: form[field] }; 
const { error } = schema.validate(data[field], { abortEarly: false });

This way it can work for passwords too

Glad to help! that's right
